# make html.checkboxfor enable true false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, razor-2

I have a kendo combobox and i have a keno html.checkboxfor control. I need to make that checkbox enable true or false base on the selected text value from the combox i am using the following code but its not working for me. I need some suggestions.

```
<tr>
    <td>Status Reason</td>
    <td>
        <div id="options">
            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                .Name("StatusReasons")
                .Placeholder("Select Status...")
                .BindTo(Model.StatusReason)
                .DataTextField("statusName")
                .DataValueField("statusIndex")
                .SelectedIndex(Convert.ToInt32(Model.StatusReasonID) - 1)
                .Events(e => e.Select("enableButton"))
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("GetStatusReasons", "Home");
                    });
                })
                .Suggest(true)
                .HtmlAttributes(Model.Editable ? new { tabindex = "2" } : (object)new { style = "width:200px", /*disabled = "disabled",*/ tabindex = "2" })
            )

        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        Name: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { disabled = true, value = "false" }) 
    </td>
    <td>
        Name 2: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ReissueDeduction, new { disabled = true, value = "false" }) 
    </td>
</tr>



function enableButton(e)
{
    if (e.item) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());

        if (dataItem.statusName == 'Reissue')
        {
            //make check box enable
        } else {
            //make check box disable
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

To disable:

```
$("#ReissueDeduction").attr("disabled", true);
```

To enable:

```
$("#ReissueDeduction").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: This is not the solution which i need.I wake to make checkboxfor enable or disable @sleeyuen

Comment: OK, so the problem is actually with enabling/disabling the checkbox? Because you only provided comments for the enabling/disabling, so I assumed you had that covered and the issue was with accessing the text of the combobox. Please confirm @RohilPatel

Comment: actual problem is to enable/disable the checkboxfor control @sleeyuen

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to fit this requirement @RohilPatel

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I think

Enable;

```
$("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox").enable();
```

Disable;

```
$("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox").disable();
```

Refered from [telekikcombobox](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/api)